# No job offers when setting location to Russia

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

I find it hard to believe that there are no job results when setting the location to Moscow, Russia or even Russia.

I first checked about a month ago? I set a few job alerts, but haven't gotten any notifications on any job offers in Russia. Isn't that weird?

I just checked to see if there were any job offers in a small city near where I live in France called Mulhouse.. And yes there is one job offer. My city proposes 4, but no job offers in Russia in over a month?

Just wanted to know if everything is working as intended or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do have one job listing for Russia, but it's targeted to people in Russia. Are you located in Russia? if not, that's why you don't see it. Otherwise, please comment back and we'll look into it.